# Has anyone attempted to deanonymze users using the Tor network?

Tags: deanonymization

Some people might benefit if they can deanonymze Tor users - law enforcement could catch criminals faster if they had control of the Tor network. Hackers also might want to deanonymze Tor users. But has anyone actually tried to deanonymize Tor users yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, people have tried to deanonymize Tor users. Some may or may not have succeeded.

This has been attempted in several ways including:

- Traffic analysis (e.g. timing correlation attacks)
- Vulnerabilities in the Tor browser (e.g. JavaScript exploits)
- 0 day exploits

---

So who is trying to deanonymize Tor users?

- Law enforcement agencies around the world have tried to deanonymize Tor users and take control the Tor network to catch criminals.
- Many governments have been working to deanonymize Tor users as well. For instance, Russia is trying to deanonymize Tor (https://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches/russia-attempted-to-de-anonymize-tor-browser-report/d/d-id/1335320).
- There was also the attack by some Carnegie Mellon University researchers who worked with the FBI to crack Tor.
- And many other organizations we may or may not know about.

Check out:

- https://restoreprivacy.com/tor
- https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/hacking-tor-online-anonymity/
- https://www.techradar.com/news/tor-browser-is-wrestling-with-a-major-security-problem

Comment: There was also the attack by some Carnegie Mellon University researchers who worked with the FBI to attack hidden services: https://www.theverge.com/2015/11/11/9719098/fbi-reportedly-paid-1-million-carnegie-mellon-tor

Comment: Also the groups trying to control exit nodes in 2020 were attempting to steal cryptocurrencies, and I don't think there was shown to be any attempt to de-anonymize people. And the "zero-day" attacks article is highly editorialized, there were no attacks and the issues discussed have been well-known for years.

Comment: @Steve thank you for the information - I will edit my post. If you have any other info on this topic, feel free to comment on it.